# Warning Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node.js, and I am trying to run an old project on my dev environment...

I get the following warning and the server will not start:

```
$ npm run start-windows

> name@0.9.0 start-windows
> set NODE_ENV=production&& forever start server/app.js

warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: server/app.js
(node:23976) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:23976) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
```

In package.json i have this:

```
"start-windows": "set NODE_ENV=production&& forever start server/app.js",
```

When I change the above line to the following the project runs fine and server starts:

```
"start-windows": "set NODE_ENV=production&& node server/app.js",
```

Dependecies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.5.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.3.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "bower": "^1.7.9",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "connect-busboy": "0.0.2",
    "d3": "^4.2.6",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "diff-json": "^0.1.11",
    "ejs": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-query-boolean": "^1.0.0",
    "fluentreports": "^1.1.3",
    "forever": "^0.15.2",
    "joi": "^10.2.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^5.7.0",
    "knex": "^0.12.9",
    "moment": "^2.15.0",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "mssql": "^3.3.0",
    "nomnom": "^1.8.1",
    "pathval": "^1.1.0",
    "pg": "^6.1.0"
  },
```

I am thinking there must be something with the forever package... or some dependency... but cant figure out a way to resolve - debug my issue. Can anyone shed some light please?

I know that there maybe some other non-deprecated libraries other than forever... but I just want to get this project to work without any fancy code changes...

Comment: Which node/forever versions are you on? You 100% sure the server does not start as those logs show only warnings?

Comment: Yes, server does not start....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that 'npm install' mess up with versions defined in package.json file and especially dependencies with later versions than the ones specified.

I tried to completely remove nodejs and then to re install the older version of node specified in the package.json but that was also getting me the same result.

The solution was to completely remove nodejs and clear the cache directories in:

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm
>
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

And THEN re-install nodejs. This saved my day